# Create a new "Site Layout" master page that shows up on the "Change the look" page?

Tags: 2013, master-page, page-layout, layouts

Right now when I go to `"Site settings" > "Look and Feel" > "Change the look" > select a theme` I only see two options in the `"Site layout"` drop-down: `Seattle` and `Oslo`. I created a copy of the Oslo master page on my site but it does not show up in the list. How can I get it to show up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you checkin and publish the master page file ?

Comment: @GautamSheth It is checked in but there is no option to publish. Do I have to have publishing feature turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross posted on MSDN and got my answer there.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84b6a33c-c45f-4b6f-802d-1bab78ae9818/create-a-new-site-layout-master-page-that-shows-up-on-the-change-the-look-page

You have to make sure there is a `.master` **and** `.preview` file.